How do I change the password of a .pfx file so that .net accepts it?
I have a .pfx file I would like to make a copy of that uses a different password.
I tried this command set:
openssl pkcs12 -in old.pfx -out tmp.pem -nodes
openssl pkcs12 -export -out new.pfx -in tmp.pem

The resulting new.pfx is indeed encrypted with the new password only; however once unpacking the encrypted pfx wrapper; the contained private key can be opened with either the old or the new password.
This construction causes .NET Runtime to choke on the .pfx file. How do I do this so that the old password is no longer accepted and thus the .NET Runtime can load it again.

Why not just use Copy to File from a certificate store? Specify the password on the next dialog, Done.

@GregAskew: Why do you assume it's a windows machine? It' s not.

I have managed to produce an answer that displeases me.
openssl rsa -in tmp.pem -out tmp2.pem
produces a broken .pem file with just the private key, however that private key is not encrypted. Therefore the following sequence of steps produces a working .pfx file.
openssl pkcs12 -in old.pfx -out tmp.pem -nodes
openssl rsa -in tmp.pem -out tmp2.pem

(edit tmp.pem; removing its encrypted private key and splicing the unencrypted private key from tmp2.pem into it)
openssl pkcs12 -export -out new.pfx -in tmp.pem

Editing the .pem file is total jank but the result works.
